# Python: Find FWHM of curve

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to find the FWHM of this curve:

```
array([  7.83891873e+10,   1.01884187e+11,   1.41597108e+11,
         2.13425504e+11,   3.62335668e+11,   6.58172740e+11,
         1.49147209e+12,   3.67126510e+12,   9.13961052e+12,
         1.51912641e+13,   1.56449601e+13,   8.75926436e+12,
         3.51770483e+12,   1.44762974e+12,   6.03263316e+11,
         3.14433592e+11,   1.93097056e+11,   1.37103090e+11,
         1.03367989e+11,   8.62706418e+10])
```

[image]
I've tried this, but it does not seem to work.

```
x = np.arange(20)
y = array
max_y = max(y)  # Find the maximum y value
max_x = x[y.index(max_y/2)]  # Find the x value corresponding to the maximum y value
print max_x, max_y
```

Comment: What is `y=array` intended to do?

Comment: It imports the array shown above

Comment: That's strange. `array([ ... ])` doesn't create an object called `array`, and therefore `y=array` doesn't import the array

Comment: What is an x-axis and y-axis in your chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
y=array([  7.83891873e+10,   1.01884187e+11,   1.41597108e+11,
         2.13425504e+11,   3.62335668e+11,   6.58172740e+11,
         1.49147209e+12,   3.67126510e+12,   9.13961052e+12,
         1.51912641e+13,   1.56449601e+13,   8.75926436e+12,
         3.51770483e+12,   1.44762974e+12,   6.03263316e+11,
         3.14433592e+11,   1.93097056e+11,   1.37103090e+11,
         1.03367989e+11,   8.62706418e+10])

max_y = max(y)  # Find the maximum y value
xs = [x for x in range(20) if y[x] > max_y/2.0]
print min(xs), max(xs) # Print the points at half-maximum
```