# Using Scherrer equation for calculating the grain size

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I'm trying to calculate the grain size by Scherrer equation but I have stuck in FWHM.

```
import numpy as np
#import math

k = 0.94
wave_length = 1.5406e-10

data = np.genfromtxt("G3.txt")

indice = np.argmax(data[:,1])
peak = (data[indice, :])
#D = (k*wave_length) / (beta*cos((math.radian(theta))
```

[image: Corresponding graphs looks likes as in the picture]

Information: [Scherrer equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scherrer_equation),  [Full width at half maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum), [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877427/python-find-fwhm-of-curve)

Comment: Please provide more information and a running code snippet. Do you want to fit a (gaussian?) to your data and extract the FWHM? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Thank your for your attention. I'm tryting to find Beta. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum#/media/File:FWHM.svg]. which is Δ(2θ).

Comment: No matter how? Then, you should look into the `scipy` module (--> curvefit). You can then define a fit-function and extract FWHM and other parameters. - In case you have tried it by yourself and encountered problems (as mentioned before): if you provide us with a working code snippet, we can work on a running example code that might solve your problem.

Comment: @nostradamus I'll check for the function. I've uploaded example text files and code snippet as your request. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pblfzwwqextrm2m/xrd%20code.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to solve this problem in python (at least for this moment). So I made it in Matlab.

```
    clear all
    clc
    A = dlmread('YOUR DATAS'); %Firstly add to path
    plot(A(:,1),A(:,2)) %Plotting the graph
    hold on

    min_peak = input('Just write a value that is higher than minimum peak values: ');
%This value must be between requested peaks and non-requested peaks (you can see this in graph)
    [yval, yval_i] = findpeaks(A(:,2),'MinPeakHeight',min_peak); %Finding peaks
    scatter(A(yval_i,1), yval); %Showing peaks
    Beta = []; 
    xval = [];
    for k = 1:size(yval_i,1) %Finding x values corresponding to y (peak) values
        xval1 = A(yval_i(k),1);
        xval = [xval xval1];
    end
        Theta = xval / 2; 

    for i = 1:size(yval,1) %Finding half of max. peak values
        yval_i1 = yval_i(i,1);
        while (yval(i,1))/2 < A(yval_i1+1,2)
        yval_i1 = yval_i1+1;
        end

        yval_i2 = yval_i(i,1);
        while (yval(i,1))/2 < A(yval_i2-1,2)
        yval_i2 = yval_i2-1;
        end

        plot(A(yval_i2,1)*ones(size(A(:,2))), A(:,2));
        plot(A(yval_i1,1)*ones(size(A(:,2))), A(:,2));
    %     hold on
    %     scatter(A(yval_i1,1),A(yval_i1,2))
    %     scatter(A(yval_i2,1),A(yval_i2,2))
        B = abs(A(yval_i1,1)-A(yval_i2,1));
        Beta = [Beta B];
    end
    Beta

    K = 0.94;
    Lambda = 1.5406e-10;

    To = [];
    for j = 1:size(Beta,2)
    To1 = (K*Lambda)/(Beta(j)*cos(Theta(j)));
    To = [To To1];
    end
    To = abs(To)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example, assuming you have a normal distribution. I run this in a Jupyter console, so in case you don't, you have to skip the "magic line" (`%matplotlib notebook`) and add `plt.show()` at the very end.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

numb = 500                                # data size
fwhm_in = 3                               # set FWHM for the artificial data
sigma = fwhm_in/2/np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))    # calculate sigma
xval = np.linspace(-10, 10, numb)         # calculate x and y values using the formula from Wikipedia (see link in question)
yval = (sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))**(-1)*np.exp(-(xval)**2/(2*sigma**2))+np.random.normal(0, 0.03, numb)

def fitFunc(x, x0, sigm):                 # this defines the fit-function
    return (sigm*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))**(-1)*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigm**2))

guess = (0.5, 2)                          # tell the code with which values it should start the iteration. Close but not equal to the real values
fitParams, fitCovariance = curve_fit(fitFunc, xval, yval, guess) # do the actual fit
print(fitParams)

print('FWHM_calc = {:.3f}'.format(fwhm_in))
fwhm_fit = 2*fitParams[1]*np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))  # calculate the FWHM from the fitted sigma ( = fitParams[1], since fitParams[0] is the offset x0)
print('FWHM_fit = {:.3f}'.format(fwhm_fit))

plt.plot(xval,yval, 'r.', label='data')
plt.plot(xval, fitFunc(xval, fitParams[0], fitParams[1]), 'k-', label='fit', linewidth = 3)

plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axvline(fwhm_fit/2, color='b')
ax.axvline(-fwhm_fit/2, color='b')
```

[image: Example for the FWHM (blue vertical lines) in a normal distribution.]

Comment: Thank you, but it looks a bit complex for me.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YBmypc9K  --> my datas looks like this and my codes for graphing is in here -> http://pastebin.com/63HRPXEm

Comment: I'm not very familiar with crystallography, but doesn't my example contain all the code you need? Which part is confusing you? Regarding your data: I plotted it quickly and I can see 5 peaks with nice resolution. Do you want to extract the FWHM of every single peak? Or rather fit an envelope, i.e. one FWHM for the signal generated by the five peaks?

Comment: Let me give a deep look to your example. Answer to your question, yes I want to extract the FWHM of every single peak and use Scherrer formula to calculate D for each peak. By the way,I also looked the linked on Stackexchange which I provided in the question. That is just what I am looking for except he ranged x values over some interval. X is angles in my case and my array is not a list. Of course although I can find for one peak without using the package what you mentioned, it might be not possible to find other peaks.

Comment: I think there are (at least) two distinct problems: (1) Extract FWHM. I prefer fitting, the link you cited in your question follows a more basic approach (i.e. basically finding the x-value which is above y_max/2). (2) Locate multiple peaks by code / math. Here, differentiating the data is always a good solution, and since you have very sharp and nicely defined peaks, this will work for sure. Is your problem mainly (1) or (2)? If you still struggle, please come back with a specific question.

Comment: I am really sorry about that even though you explain everything carefully I still struggle with editing your code for my own case. Yet I am really very new in python so excuse me for taking your time to much.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, as long as you never stop trying it yourself. I fitted the five peaks in your data and got 5 values for the FWHMs. The most important thing is to adjust the `guess`-parameters in order to facilitate fitting. I will add a few comments to my code above. - I'm still ready and willing to support you, in case you have a concrete problem.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ha5xWDvn. I thought that it might be easier to clarify the process by changing your codes and comments in your code a little bit. So it might be prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: You can fit whatever function you like... I typed a typical normal distribution, but you can also use Gauss etc. Your code looks pretty okay, except one thing: The `guess` values are for the parameters in the `def fitFunc`, i.e. the first value in `guess` is for `x0` (the x-offset) and the second for the `sigma` (i.e. basically FWHM, with a few prefactors). What is your problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for sharing this as an answer but comments does not provide me upload a picture to clarify the problem. So I've illustrated the problem with an image below (BTW, I can't edit or delete my comments which I wrote reluctantly).
I got this graph when I run your code
[image: I got this graph when I run your code]

[image: This is the graph what I'm looking for]

This graph illustrates what I'm looking for

Comment: The proper way would be to add four Normal Distributions, i.e. you have to extend the function and will you will have 8 or 12 fit variables in the end (x-offset, FWHM and probably y-offset for each of the four peaks). This could get messy with the fitting routine, so maybe it would be better to fit each peak separately with a single Normal Distribution. What is your problem when you do that? For the `guess`-values, you should just use a rough guess for each of the values, i.e. for the first peak from the left: x0 = 40 (x-offset), sigma = 0.5 (and probably you have to add y0 = -10 (y-offset)).

Comment: @nostradamus. I appreciate your help. My friend gave a hard try to make it in MATLAB after me explained every single step of my request. He also shared the code. I will come back later again, when I'm ready to do it in Python.